# FTP from Windows Explorer in active mode?

Tags: windows-explorer, ftp

I'd like to use Windows Explorer to connect to an FTP site in active move. Where and what do I have to configure to enable this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is configured from the Control Panel -- Internet Options in particular.  Go to the Advanced tab and scroll down until you find a checkbox labeled "Use Passive FTP (for firewall and DSL modem compatibility)".  Uncheck it.

Yes, Windows Explorer follows Internet Explorer's settings.

Comment: Is there any way to configure this on a site by site basis (i.e. non-global setting)?

Comment: @codescribblr: No. If you need that you'll need to use a proper FTP client.

Comment: What are the default Explorer options so i can mimic them exactly in my FTP client?

Comment: @theB3RV: IIRC, Explorer defaults to Active Mode FTP.  I can't think of any other FTP-specific options for Explorer off the top of my head.