# Filezilla doesn't connect to my ftp but I can connect to ftp using same details in Windows explorer or browser

Tags: ftp, http, filezilla

Filezilla does not connect to my ftp but I can connect to ftp using same details in Windows explorer or browser using ftp://ftp.xxxxx.com

Log is:

```
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Status: Resolving address of ftp.xxxxx.com
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Status: Connecting to 50.87.57.52:21...
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Response: 220-You are user number 5 of 1000 allowed.
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Response: 220-Local time is now 11:01. Server port: 21.
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Response: 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Response: 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Response: 234 AUTH TLS OK.
2015-10-05 22:31:27 6908 1 Status: Initializing TLS...
2015-10-05 22:31:28 6908 1 Status: Verifying certificate...
2015-10-05 22:31:28 6908 1 Status: TLS connection established.
2015-10-05 22:31:28 6908 1 Command: USER upload@xxxxx.com
2015-10-05 22:31:28 6908 1 Response: 331 User xxx@xxxxx.com OK. Password required
2015-10-05 22:31:28 6908 1 Command: PASS *********
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Command: SYST
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Command: FEAT
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response: 211-Extensions supported:
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  EPRT
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  IDLE
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  MDTM
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  SIZE
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  MFMT
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  REST STREAM
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  MLSD
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  AUTH TLS
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  PBSZ
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  PROT
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  ESTA
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  PASV
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  EPSV
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  SPSV
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response:  ESTP
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Response: 211 End.
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
2015-10-05 22:31:29 6908 1 Command: PBSZ 0
2015-10-05 22:31:30 6908 1 Response: 200 PBSZ=0
2015-10-05 22:31:30 6908 1 Command: PROT P
2015-10-05 22:31:30 6908 1 Response: 200 Data protection level set to "private"
2015-10-05 22:31:30 6908 1 Status: Connected
2015-10-05 22:31:30 6908 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2015-10-05 22:31:30 6908 1 Command: PWD
2015-10-05 22:31:30 6908 1 Response: 257 "/" is your current location
2015-10-05 22:31:30 6908 1 Command: TYPE I
2015-10-05 22:31:30 6908 1 Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
2015-10-05 22:31:30 6908 1 Command: PASV
2015-10-05 22:31:31 6908 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (50,87,57,52,176,86)
2015-10-05 22:31:31 6908 1 Command: MLSD
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Status: Disconnected from server
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Status: Resolving address of ftp.xxxxx.com
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Status: Connecting to 50.87.57.52:21...
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Response: 220-You are user number 6 of 1000 allowed.
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Response: 220-Local time is now 11:01. Server port: 21.
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Response: 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Response: 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Response: 234 AUTH TLS OK.
2015-10-05 22:31:51 6908 1 Status: Initializing TLS...
2015-10-05 22:31:52 6908 1 Status: Verifying certificate...
2015-10-05 22:31:52 6908 1 Status: TLS connection established.
2015-10-05 22:31:52 6908 1 Command: USER xxx@xxxxx.com
2015-10-05 22:31:52 6908 1 Response: 331 User xxx@xxxxx.com OK. Password required
2015-10-05 22:31:52 6908 1 Command: PASS *********
2015-10-05 22:31:53 6908 1 Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
2015-10-05 22:31:53 6908 1 Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
2015-10-05 22:31:53 6908 1 Command: PBSZ 0
2015-10-05 22:31:53 6908 1 Response: 200 PBSZ=0
2015-10-05 22:31:53 6908 1 Command: PROT P
2015-10-05 22:31:53 6908 1 Response: 200 Data protection level set to "private"
2015-10-05 22:31:53 6908 1 Status: Connected
2015-10-05 22:31:53 6908 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2015-10-05 22:31:53 6908 1 Command: PWD
2015-10-05 22:31:54 6908 1 Response: 257 "/" is your current location
2015-10-05 22:31:54 6908 1 Command: TYPE I
2015-10-05 22:31:54 6908 1 Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
2015-10-05 22:31:54 6908 1 Command: PASV
2015-10-05 22:31:54 6908 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (50,87,57,52,180,60)
2015-10-05 22:31:54 6908 1 Command: MLSD
2015-10-05 22:32:14 6908 1 Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
2015-10-05 22:32:14 6908 1 Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: Do you have an access to server-side logs? Can you show us a log for the session from Windows Explorer/browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things I'd suggest trying which might explain the difference:

1. First try changing Filezilla from PASV / PASSIVE mode to ACTIVE mode.
2. If that doesn't work, try connecting without encryption in Filezilla (unencrypted FTP may be what Windows explorer is using but Filezilla appears to be using TLS encryption).  I recommend using encryption for FTP, but I'm just listing what might be a difference.

Comment: Related: [FTP from Windows Explorer in active mode?](http://superuser.com/questions/249731/ftp-from-windows-explorer-in-active-mode)

Comment: Plain non-encrypted FTP worked. Thanks a lot.